# How to create a null-terminated string in Go?

Tags: string, go, c-strings

How to create a null-terminated `string` in Go?

What I'm currently trying is `a:="golang\0"` but it is showing compilation error:

```
non-octal character in escape sequence: "
```

Comment: If you need it, use `0` insted to get your work done.

Comment: See: https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals .

Comment: NUL is escaped as `\x00` in strings. Also, the language doesn't provide NUL-terminated strings so.. yes, you are forced to modify every string.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[Spec: String literals:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals)

> The text between the quotes forms the value of the literal, with backslash escapes interpreted as they are in [rune literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals) (except that `\'` is illegal and `\"` is legal), with the same restrictions. The three-digit octal (`\nnn`) and two-digit hexadecimal (`\xnn`) escapes represent individual bytes of the resulting string; all other escapes represent the (possibly multi-byte) UTF-8 encoding of individual characters.

So `\0` is an illegal sequence, you have to use 3 octal digits:

```
s := "golang\000"
```

Or use hex code (2 hex digits):

```
s := "golang\x00"
```

Or a unicode sequence (4 hex digits):

```
s := "golang\u0000"
```

Example:

```
s := "golang\000"
fmt.Println([]byte(s))
s = "golang\x00"
fmt.Println([]byte(s))
s = "golang\u0000"
fmt.Println([]byte(s))
```

Output: all end with a 0-code byte (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oKDlycXfsK)).

```
[103 111 108 97 110 103 0]
[103 111 108 97 110 103 0]
[103 111 108 97 110 103 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the `ByteSliceFromString` function:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

func main() {
   b, e := windows.ByteSliceFromString("golang")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   fmt.Printf("%q\n", string(b)) // "golang\x00"
}
```

- https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/unix#ByteSliceFromString
- https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#ByteSliceFromString

Answer (score 1):

@icza describes how to write a string literal with a null terminator.  Use this code to add a null to the end of a string variable:

```
 s += string(rune(0))
```

Example:

```
s := "hello"
s += string(rune(0))
fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)  // prints "hello\x00"
```