# Golang string end character

Tags: go

I'm a newbie in Golang, so I'm playing with some algorithms and i have a little problem.
In java for insert an end string in char array I can do like this:

```
String str = "Mr John Smith    ";
char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
arr[12] = '\0';
```

But in Golang I'm trying like this:

```
str := []byte("Mr John Smith    ")
str[12] = '\0'
```

But this code didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there anyway to create null terminated string in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007361/is-there-anyway-to-create-null-terminated-string-in-go/38008565#38008565)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a valid syntax for a rune literal with a 0 value. You can use the hex escape sequence

```
str[12] = '\x00'
```

If you really need an octal value, it requires 3 digits

```
str[12] = '\000'
```

Or just assign a literal `0`

```
str[12] = 0
```

You can see the valid rune literal escape sequences in the specification: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals