# how to split string by ascii header 0x01

Tags: go, split, ascii

As the title says, my question is how to split a utf8 string by **ascii** header 0x01 in Go.

```
str := "" // 'str' contains 0x01
strings.Split(str, "0x01") // is not work
```

Comment: The string literal that contains a codepoint of `1` is `"\x01"` and not `"0x01"`. See [Is there anyway to create null terminated string in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007361/is-there-anyway-to-create-null-terminated-string-in-go/38008565#38008565)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `string(uint64(1))` as separator.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    str := "foo" + string(uint64(1)) + "bar"                                      
    fmt.Printf("%#v", strings.Split(str, string(uint64(1)))) 
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/hnjF4jk_p_1