# DLL Injection Using Golang(CreateRemoteThread)

Tags: windows, go, winapi, hook, dll-injection

I'm trying to do DLL Injection using Golang.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/JamesHovious/w32"
    "syscall"
)

func main(){
    //just a random dll
    dllPath := "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wevtapi.dll"
    procID := 8124
    hProc, handleErr  := w32.OpenProcess(w32.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, uint32(procID))
    if handleErr != nil{
        fmt.Println("handleErr:", handleErr)
    }
    kernel32DLL, dllLoadErr := syscall.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
    if dllLoadErr != nil{
        fmt.Println("dllLoadErr:", dllLoadErr)
    }
    addr, addrErr := syscall.GetProcAddress(syscall.Handle(kernel32DLL), "LoadLibraryA")
    if addrErr != nil{
        fmt.Println("addrErr:", addrErr)
    }
    arg, allocErr := w32.VirtualAllocEx(hProc, 0, len(dllPath)*2, w32.MEM_RESERVE | w32.MEM_COMMIT, w32.PAGE_READWRITE)
    if allocErr != nil{
        fmt.Println("allocErr:", allocErr)
    }
    writeErr := w32.WriteProcessMemory(hProc, uint32(arg), []byte(dllPath), 0)
    if writeErr != nil{
        fmt.Println("writeErr:", writeErr)
    }
    _, _, threadErr := w32.CreateRemoteThread(hProc, nil, 0, uint32(addr), arg, 0)
    if threadErr != nil{
        fmt.Println("threadErr:", threadErr)
    }
}
```

It doesn't return any error, but I can't see wevtapi.dll under targeted process in Process Explorer.
The process I'm targeting is 32bit version of Notepad++.
Executable is compiled for 32bit too.
I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

**ADDITION**:
I'm using 64bit version of windows

Comment: String literals in golang aren't zero-terminated. This is different from C, and a C API (such as `LoadLibraryA`) requires strings to be zero-terminated. It is unclear why you are allocating `len(dllPath)*2` bytes. What's the reason for this?

Comment: I read some answers where the problem was not allocating enough space. I just randomly wrote that to get that problem out of my mind.

Comment: I edited this line: dllPath := "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wevtapi.dll\000" and it didn't solve the problem. Is this a correct solution to the problem you're indicating? Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007361/is-there-anyway-to-create-null-terminated-string-in-go

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine. Problem was using 64bit DLL (C:\Windows\System32\wevtapi.dll). 32bit DLLs on 64bit windows are located in C:\Windows\SysWOW64.